# Change existing model data with form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to implement a view that displays a form to capture data and a table with the captured data of a user. The table has a form with two buttons per row, either submitting "change" or "delete" together with the object id of the object in the given table row, using POST.

My Django view looks like this:

```
def captureData(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'delete' in request.POST:
            # User hits "Delete" button in displayed objects table.
            try:
                del_object = MyObject.objects.filter(user = request.user).get(id = request.POST['delete'])
                del_object.delete()
            except:
                # Do something ... 
            return redirect('captureData')
        elif 'change' in request.POST:
            # User hits "Change" button in displayed objects table.
            ch_object = MyObject.objects.filter(user = request.user).get(id = request.POST['change'])
            form = MyForm(instance = ch_object)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('captureData')
        else:
            # New data to be added to the database.
            if form.is_valid():
                new_object = form.save(commit = False)
                new_object.user = request.user
                new_object.save()
            return redirect('captureData')

    objects = Object.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    context = {'form': form, 'objects': objects}
    return render(request, 'myTemplate.html', context)
```

This is how the myTemplate.html looks like:

```
{%  extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
        <h3>Data capturing</h3>
        <p>
            <!-- First form, responsible for capturing data -->
            <form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
                {{form}}
                <input type ='submit' value='Save'/>
            </form>
        </p>
        <h3>Captured data</h3>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for object in objects %}
                    <tr>
                    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                    <td>{{object.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{object.address}}</td>
                    <td>{{object.city}}</td>
                    <!-- Second form (per row), responsible for submitting a "delete" or "change" -->
                    <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                        <td>
                        <button type="submit" value="{{object.id}}" name="change" id="object{{object.id}}">Change</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <button type="submit" value="{{object.id}}" name="delete" id="object{{object.id}}">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
{% endblock %}
```

The "delete" part works fine. The problem is the "change" part. It successfully populates the form with the selected objects data, but when I hit the capture from submit button it runs into the `else:` clause resulting in a new data row or an error, if the data already exists. The reason for this is obvious: The new POST data does not contain the "change" marker anymore.

How can I separate the `elif:` part from the `else:` part?

Comment: Could you also share your `myTemplate.html` file please?

Comment: Why does the POST data not contain `"change"` if that is what you want?

Comment: I don't understand your "obvious" reason. If you have 'change' in the form, it will go to your elif block not the else one.

Comment: The "change" data is created by the form in the table (see template above). Once an empty form is populated via "change", the user hits "Submit" and the view does not get "change" in the POST data, since the data capture form is used.